# how to calculate bins for densehistogram and for histogrambox.generateHistogram in c#?

Tags: c#, image-processing, visual-studio-2015, emgucv

Please help me understand how to interpret histograms and calculate bins to be put in generating histograms. First of all, I am still a student and I am confused on the things I have read from my research. I have read that to calculate a bin, you need  to know the range of the data(dataset?). My problem is that I do not know how to get the data and the range of data in my image.

**The DenseHistogram asks for these parameters....**

```
DenseHistogram x = new DenseHistogram(int binSize, RangeF range);
```

**My code is below** and I just copied this from another person here so I can try it and I really want to understand **how he got 256 for binSize and 0-256 for range**

```
DenseHistogram hist = new DenseHistogram(256, new RangeF(0, 256));
```

and

my problem here Ma'am/Sir, is that my histogram looks different from other histograms I have seen on the internet and, again, the binSize.
the histogram looks like [click here to view histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCAtT.png) and this is the image used for **generateHistograms** [click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Xoa.jpg) , it is different from others and I have noticed that if I changed the number of bins, the lines also change. This is why I want to know how many bins I should put in....

```
histogramBox.generateHistograms(IImage image, int numberOfBins);
```

**Please help me understand and can you please explain why the histogram looked like that?** **THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!!!**

Comment: The histogram seems normal. Different from mine, but normal. Also, the range goes from `0..255` because I assume you are using and 8-bit per channel image. [Here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/e4db3e6c-bcef-a7bd-d335-62b9a6eb61ff.htm) is the help page on `DenseHistogram`.

Comment: I don't know what is an 8-bit per channel image, I only got it from the internet for testing. I want to understand how many bins I should use for an image and how to interpret the histogram on the image I linked. Please help me understand, thank you